# When i pass 1 into n i do not get [0,1] i get [1]?

Tags: javascript

This is Fibonacci Generator function that i have created but for some reason i can't seem to get the output for 1 = [0,1] . While it works alright for other conditions.If somebody can point me at what i am doing wrong here.

```js
function bl(n) {
  var output = [];
  var firstNo = 0;
  var secondNo = 1;

  if (n === 0) {
    output.push(0);
  }
  if (n === 1) {
    output.push(0);
    output.push(1);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var sum = firstNo + secondNo;
      firstNo = secondNo;
      secondNo = sum;
      output.push(sum);
    }
    return output;
  }
}
console.log(bl(1));
```

Comment: you don't return `output` from outside of the `else` - is that intended?>

Comment: Good question! i did not see that it is working fine now.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`return output` had to be executed for all conditions so just execute it at end of your function.

```js
function bl(n) {
  var output = [];
  var firstNo = 0;
  var secondNo = 1;

  if (n === 0) {
    output.push(0);
  }
  if (n === 1) {
    output.push(0);
    output.push(1);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var sum = firstNo + secondNo;
      firstNo = secondNo;
      secondNo = sum;
      output.push(sum);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
console.log(bl(1));
```